# How can I align 2 elements to opposite ends of a container element based on text direction using only CSS?

Tags: css

Using only CSS (consider the HTML and JS are set in stone) How can I align a label, and an accompanying sudo element (icon) at opposite ends of a container element? Any solution provided must be text direction sensitive and use the elements *computed* text direction as the actual container wont have a dir attribute in the HTML. so in other words even though the JSfiddle has the 2nd HTML element with a dir="rtl" attribute, you cant do this:

```
div[dir="rtl"] {
...
}
```

In LTR directions I am trying to get something that looks like this:

```
|some text                           (icon)|
```

While in RTL languages I desire the opposite:

```
|(icon)                           txet emos|
```

[Here is the JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ob9hv5a2/1/)

Comment: I assume you're passing the direction attribute to the HTML or `body` then?

Comment: No. I don't set the text direction myself. The page in question is one part of a mobile webapp that uses some earlier app page to set the user's language (not built by me). That's how text direction is determined but unfortunately searching the entire page with `[dir]` yields no results. Honestly I have no idea what is setting the text direction, I just know its there and I have to deal with it. Direction is properly respected by CSS styles that are sensitive to direction (`text-alignment: start;`) for example.